# 404 error in / login Laravel

Tags: php, cpanel, laravel-5.3

I migrate a web page made in Laravel to a server witch Cpanel, 
all the routes are working find except the Auths like /login. 
When you try to enter there route it appear a 404 error.
 Here is the page: http://elgloborojocatalogos.com.mx/

And my routes are :

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

// Routes or function calls for this project.
Route::get('/', 'GlobosController@catalogo');

Route::get('globos',['uses' =>'GlobosController@index']);

Route::post('globos/store',['uses' =>'GlobosController@store'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('globos/retrieveall',['uses' => 'GlobosController@retrieveAll'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('globos/retrieve/{no_pages}',['uses'=> 'GlobosController@retrieve'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('globos/pages',['uses'=>'GlobosController@pages'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('globos/pagesp/{type}', ['uses' =>'GlobosController@pagesp'])->middleware('auth');   

Route::get('/home', function(){ return redirect('globos/pages');});

Route::delete('globos/deleteGlobo/{id}', ['uses' =>'GlobosController@deleteGlobo'])->middleware('auth');

Route::post('globos/findGlobo',['uses'=>'GlobosController@findGlobo'])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('globos/imprimirCatalogo',['uses'=>'GlobosController@imprimirCatalogo'])->middleware('auth');

//Users
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Comment: What version of PHP is running on the server?

Comment: The helper function Auth::routes() will register for you the Route::get('login'), Route::post('login'), Route::post('logout') and some other (registration, password forgot). You do not ave to add them manually. The best thing is to do an `php artisan route:list` and see the output on that one.

Comment: In the server we are using php 5.6.4 @JeremyHarris

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to access http://elgloborojocatalogos.com.mx/login , But it shows file not found. which is pretty obvious, because you are missing index.php before login like below

```
http://elgloborojocatalogos.com.mx/index.php/login
```

Now it will do the trick, but sure it looks ugly. So for removing index.php you need to add a .htaccess file in the public_html folder, which is root. So, simply create a file and name it **.htaccess** and copy paste this following line of code to the file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase //
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It should work as expected now

Comment: This doesn't work with Laravel signed URL. Please improve this answer. Correct version is this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647507/1093811

Answer (score 0):

Most of your routes are giving us a 404, example:

[image]

Event `/globos` which has no middlewares. So I'll have to assume we are not looking to the same app you have in your development environment. Have you uploaded it correctly?

If it was only an auth problem a page like `/globos/pages` should redirect us to auth, but that doesn't happen, so it's a general routes problem.

Also `Auth::routes();` should give you login, logout and register, so you don't need to create any other login routes, or, you may just delete that `Auth::routes();` line.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `.htaccess` as mentioned by answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647507/1093811

Below works with Laravel signed URLs as well.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```