# Each route is showing 404 message on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to deploy a `laravel` application on [A2Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/) shared hosting. My document root is: **/public_html** directory. I uploaded everything from my `laravel` application except the public folder to the /beta directory of hosting.

And then I uploaded everything from the public directory to the **/public_html** directory.

In my index.php file, I changed the following two lines:

```
require __DIR__.'/../beta/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../beta/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now I am only seeing the home page of my application correctly. That is, mydomain.com. Any hyperlink followed by mydomain.com is showing a **404 message**. In my view files, this is how I am referring to a path:

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

But after deploying the application, whenever I hit that link, i.e. mydomain.com/login, I get the `404 Not Found: The resource requested could not be found on this server!` message. I tried changing `/login` to `login` in the `<a>` tag. Same result. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you give this url a try in separate tab `mydomain.com/index.php/login`

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache / Nginx? Are you routing all non file/directory requests through your root / bootstrap file? (e.g. /public_html/index.php)

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, bro you blew my mind. Yes it is now showing the login page :/ What went wrong?

Comment: @Eisenheim, I just posted my answer, give it a try. If it still does not work, I can think of one another possible issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eisenheim, this is htaccess issue: get one `.htaccess` file in root folder of your web-project.

And put the following code inside it,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then try without `index.php` it should work perfectly.

Comment: When you say root folder of your web-project, do you mean the public folder of the laravel application which I copied to /public_html folder, or the laravel application root which I copied to the /beta folder?

Comment: laravel folder root. so yes, inside `beta` folder. Where you can see composer.json and composer.lock etc files.

Comment: Added the .htaccess file and tried without index.php, didn't work

Comment: And still with index.php/login, I have the access. If that information helps you...

Comment: Can you check with phpinfo() function if `modrewrite` is enabled and loaded ?

Comment: is it laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: You can follow the steps described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel) for Laravel 5.4 in 1st answer or in 2nd answer its mentioned how to do with laravel 4.2

Comment: Laravel 5.5. PHP version 7.0.24. There is no such thing as modrewrite in my phpinfo() output. Used ctrl+f and searched for modrewrite

Comment: ok, if it is ubuntu/linux server then, you can execute this command using ssh login via console: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (to enable modrewrite) and then restart apache using this: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: It worked when I added the .htaccess file to the /public_html folder. So I guess the htaccess should be added to public folder of the laravel and not the application root.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer for those hosting PHP on a Windows environment using IIS, remember you'll need a web.config file with the rewrites configured to serve Laravel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```